# Couldn't establish connection to TcpListener

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

For the last 2 weeks I've been trying to solve a problem, apparently unsuccessfully.
I have a server, using TcpListener class, and a client, using TcpClient class.

My tests were using 2 computers in my internal home network (level 1 router). 
Trying to connect, client-computer got "connection request timeout" exception.

What I've already tried:

1. Running the client and the server on the same computer - worked
2. Listening on 0.0.0.0 port 6666 (check with netstat to make sure that the server is listening)
3. Disable both client and server firewalls
4. Trying to connect **my** remote application with telnet (to reject "client code bug" possibilty)
5. Installing telnet on both computers, and connecting **successfully**.

Still **my** server does not seem to get any connection. Client computer is Windows XP and server computer is Windows 7.

Please help, I'm really stuck on this one.

Edit - Server code ->

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Utils
{
    public class ClientConnection
{
    public ClientConnection(IPHostEntry hostName, TcpClient client)
    {
        HostName = hostName;
        Client = client;
    }

    public IPHostEntry HostName { get; set; }

    public TcpClient Client { get; set; }
}

public class SocketServer : IDisposable
{

    private const int DefaultRecieveSize = 1024;
    protected const int ReceiveTimeoutBeforeQuiting = 5000;

    private readonly Encoding _defaultEncoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    private readonly TcpListener _socket;

    protected Dictionary<IPAddress, ClientConnection> Clients;
    private static object _locker;

    private readonly AutoResetEvent _listeningStopEvent;
    private readonly Thread _listeningThread;

    private readonly AutoResetEvent _acceptNewClientEvent;

    public delegate void ClientsListChangedEvent();
    public event ClientsListChangedEvent ClientsChangedEvent;

    private Timer _refreshClientsTimer;
    private static int _updateClientListInterval;

    #region Ctors

    protected SocketServer(int port)
    {
        _socket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"),port);
        Clients = new Dictionary<IPAddress, ClientConnection>();

        _updateClientListInterval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateClientListInterval"]);


        _listeningThread = new Thread(AcceptNewConnections);
        _listeningStopEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        _acceptNewClientEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _locker = new object();

        _socket.Start();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Send methods

    protected void SendString(IPAddress client, string data)
    {
        // implementation here
    }

    #endregion

    #region Receieve methods

    protected MemoryStream GetInputDataAsMemoryStream(IPAddress client)
    {
        // implementation here    
    }

    protected string GetInputDataAsMemoryString(IPAddress client)
    {
        // implementation here    
    }

    protected string GetInputDataAsMemoryString(IPAddress client, int timeout)
    {
        // implementation here    
    }  

    #endregion

    #region Listening methons

    public void StopListening()
    {
        _listeningStopEvent.Set();

        // todo : check if works
        _refreshClientsTimer.Dispose();
    }

    public bool StartListening()
    {
        if (_listeningThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
        {
            _listeningThread.Start();

            // start refreshing clients list too. update clients list every 10 seconds
            _refreshClientsTimer = new Timer(UpdateList, null, 0, _updateClientListInterval * 1000);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void AddClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // get all needed data before entering lock 
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            TcpClient client;
            try
            {
                client = _socket.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                // probebly server has been closed. exit
                return;
            }

            var clientEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
            var ip = SocketFunctions.ExtractIpFromEndPoint(clientEndPoint);
            IPHostEntry hostName;
            try
            {
                hostName = SocketFunctions.ExtractHostnameFromEndPoint(clientEndPoint);
            }
            catch(SocketException)
            {
                // error while parsing from ip to host name. Put default
                hostName = new IPHostEntry();
            }


            // check if given ip already connected
            if (!Clients.ContainsKey(ip))
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    Clients.Add(ip, new ClientConnection(hostName, client));
                }

                // notify that a new clients has been added
                ClientsChangedEvent.Invoke();
            }
        }
        // a new client has accepted
        _acceptNewClientEvent.Set();
    }

    private void AcceptNewConnections(object obj)
    {
        var shouldStop = false;

        while (!shouldStop)
        {
            _socket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AddClientCallback, null);

            AutoResetEvent[] events = { _listeningStopEvent, _acceptNewClientEvent };
            var result = WaitHandle.WaitAny(events);

            if (result == 0)
            {
                shouldStop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion 

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetConnectedClients()
    {
        var connectedClients = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (var client in Clients)
            {
                // get only connected clients. Don`t remove - next Timer round will do it anyway and I don`t want to lock _clients
                if (client.Value.Client.Connected)
                {
                    connectedClients.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(client.Key.ToString(), client.Value.HostName.HostName));
                }
            }
        }

        return connectedClients;
    }

    private static void CheckConnectionStatus(TcpClient client)
    {
        if (client.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            var checkConn = new byte[1];
            checkConn[0] = 0;
            try
            {
                if (client.Client.Receive(checkConn, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0)
                {
                    throw new IOException();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                // for me, both exceptions mean that there was a conncetion error. Throw IOException for this case too
                throw new IOException();
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateList(object obj)
    {
        // iterate each client and check its state. Remove if not connected
        var tempClients = new Dictionary<IPAddress, ClientConnection>(Clients);
        var changedOccurred = false;

        lock (_locker)
        {
            foreach (var client in Clients)
            {
                try
                {
                    CheckConnectionStatus(client.Value.Client);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    // client is not connected anymore
                    tempClients.Remove(client.Key);
                    changedOccurred = true;
                }

            }
        }

        if (changedOccurred)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                Clients = tempClients;
            }

            // notify that a new clients has been added
            ClientsChangedEvent.Invoke();
        }

    }

    #region IDisposble

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            StopListening();
            _socket.Stop();
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide client code? I guess server should be OK if you were able to telnet it...

Comment: And what happens if you run both applications on the same host?

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev thanks for quick reponse. About client code, it is not neccessery because I couldn`t conncet with a simple telnet client either. @MortenMertner if I activate both my client and server on the same computer, it works (meaning the server gets a new conncetion)

Comment: Is your client trying connect to the server by hostname or IP address?

Comment: Internal ip address, which I staticly configured with my router (192.168.123.66)

Comment: @JohnAdam - And you're able to ping the server's IP address without issue from the client pc?

Comment: @JohnAdam use wireshark if you can see any connection or packet sent over socket?

Comment: I already used wireshark and on server computer I saw client`s packets for my ip with wanted port, but stil - no reaction from server application..

Comment: @JohnAdam - This is where your server code would be helpful. If the packets are actually arriving at the server according to Wireshark then the problem is going to be in your code.

Comment: @M.Babcock I`ve added server code. Hope it will be more clearer now.
@Sergey Kudriavtsev

Comment: @JohnAdam - What happens when you switch your `IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0")` with `IPAddress.Any` or explicitly use `IPAddress.Parse("192.168.123.66")`?

Comment: @M.Babcock already tried. Still no luck..By the way, I do manage to establish a telnet session between 2 computer (I installed telnet clients and server)

Comment: @JohnAdam - The Windows telnet server would automatically add an exception to Windows firewall so it isn't a valid test. When you say in your question that you were able to successfully use telnet, were you referring to using the telnet client on your client PC connecting to the telnet server on the server machine; or did you use the telnet client to connect to your application on the server?

Comment: @M.Babcock using on client computer in order to connect to server computer. And about firwall suspicous, I turned off completely my firwall and still it didn`t work. Maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: @JohnAdam - That didn't answer the question (please be explicit). Are you using the telnet client on the client machine to connect to your application on the server? As in `telnet 192.168.123.66 6666`. This would eliminate all doubts that the client isn't working correctly.

Comment: @M.Babcock oh, sure I tried it - Didn`t work.

Comment: @JohnAdam - Given the facts: 1. The client connects when run from the same machine as the server. 2. Using telnet to replace your client in to test, didn't work. 3. Other network services (such as a telnet server) can be connected to from the client machine without issue. That provides enough information for me to know that this isn't a programming problem, so I'm going to flag your question to be moved to SU where they can help you diagnose your networking/firewall issues. (It is generally considered off topic for SO.)

Comment: This can't be migrated to SU. While the problem might be the firewall, the question (as written) is a _programming_ question. If you'd like, I can close this as too localized and you can ask on a sister site for help diagnosing the connection issue.